# Why is the output giving me a value of +1?

Tags: c#

The code

```
public static void InitializeArray(ref double[] doubleA)
{
    //array init using foreach
    int i = 0;
    foreach (double dub in doubleA)
    {
        doubleA[i++] = i + .5;
    }
}
```

is giving me an output of

```
doubleA[0] = 1.5 instead of .5

doubleA[1] = 2.5 instead of 1.5
```

and so on

I'm not understanding why it's doing that. As I understand it, `doubleA[0]` should be getting 0.5 because I'm only adding 0.5 so where is the extra 1 coming from? I'm thinking it's from int i but for i=0, shouldn't it evaluate to `doubleA[0] = 0 + .5`?

So far I have tried writing `doubleA[i++] = i + .5;` instead which gives each element in the array just the value of 0.5.

Comment: `i++` increments the `i` before performing `i + .5;`

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Interesting, I learnt something from this. Bonus points if one of the answers can clearly explain why `++` evaluates before the right side even though it is on the left-side of the `=`. I assume because of operator precedence (i.e. `++` is before `=`)?

Comment: A good rule of thumb: Never do what your code does (mutate a variable with and incrementing or decrementing expression and consume the same variable). Though the behavior is well specified in the C# spec, either you or the next reader of your code will get it wrong. Had you put `++i;` on the next line of code, your intent, and the code, would have been much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's start with `i = 0`

```
doubleA[i++] = i + .5;
```

Here you are accessing position `0` of the array, but also adding `1` to the value of `i`. When `i == 0`, the *expression* `i++` will be the value `0`, but the value of the variable `i` is incremented such that the new value of `i` is `1`.

On the right hand side, this new value of `i` is used (`1`) and added to `0.5`. Giving a value of `1.5` which is assigned back to index `0` of the array (as indicated on the left hand side of the assignment).

I could go on, but I think you probably get it by now...

[Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) on `operator ++`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. And to avoid this problem, basically I would just put the increment on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `i` is being incremented in your key: `doubleA[i++]`. `i++` will increment the key by one, **AFTER** returning it. When it's used later (as the value), its value has already been incremented. So now you're setting it to `1 + 0.5`.

Let's break this down, and show you the functional equivalent, and you'll see exactly what this is happening:

```
public static void InitializeArray(ref double[] doubleA)
{
    //array init using foreach
    int i = 0;
    foreach (double dub in doubleA)
    {
        int key = i;
        i = i + 1;
        doubleA[key] = i + .5;
    }
}
```